# JQuery Chrome retrieve height of an element

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am working with a dynamic table

I want to get the height of one row to apply it to another row, here is the code

```
if($(".row0_fixed").height()>($(".row0").height())){
  $(".row0").height($(".row0_fixed").height());
}else{
  $(".row0_fixed").height($(".row0").height());
}
```

And the code works good on firefox, but the problem is in chrome, is not retriving the right height of the row, not even in the console, if a make a query like this

```
$(".row0").height()
```

The retrieved height in the console is not right, for example it puts 148px when the real height is 198px, I can see this because is not right in the console, but is right on the screen of the site.

Jquery version 1.11.0

Chrome version Version 33.0.1750.117 m

Thanks

Comment: did you check the height of said element in "Layout Box" under F12, I am sure it is same as what jquery return and not what you desire. This might be because your CSS has TD height set as 148px. Or provide more details like HTML of said table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [.outerHeight( [includeMargin ] )](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/#outerHeight-includeMargin)

> Description: Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding, border, and optionally margin. Returns a number (without "px") representation of the value or null if called on an empty set of elements.

If you want outerHeight including margins

```
$(".row0").outerHeight(true);
```

> The top and bottom padding and border are always included in the .outerHeight() calculation; if the includeMargin argument is set to true, the margin (top and bottom) is also included.

or

Without margin

```
$(".row0").outerHeight();
```